# SocialCommentManager GetComment Count on friendly urls

Tags: social

The function below returns me the number of the comments on a url. 
However, if the page saved with a friendly url, then the result of the function is always "0"

Do you have any idea, how can I get the number of comments on friendy urls?

```
    private static string GetCommentsCount(SPListItem item)
    {
        var commentsCount = "0";
        if (item[Constants.PublishingPageAbsoluteUrlFieldName] != null)
        {
            var pageUrl = item[Constants.PublishingPageAbsoluteUrlFieldName].ToString();

            var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.Current;
            var socialCommentManager = new SocialCommentManager(serviceContext);
            var pageUri = new Uri(pageUrl);

            commentsCount = socialCommentManager.GetCount(pageUri).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return commentsCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using the TaxonomyNavigation.TryParseFriendlyUrl method in order to build the url.

```
    private static string GetCommentsCount(SPListItem item, string url)
    {
        var commentsCount = "0";

        if (item[Constants.PublishingPageAbsoluteUrlFieldName] != null)
        {
            // aspx page
            var pageUrl = item[Constants.PublishingPageAbsoluteUrlFieldName].ToString();

            // Friendly url
            if (!url.EndsWith(".aspx"))
            {
                NavigationTerm term;
                string[] catalogUrlSegments;

                TaxonomyNavigation.TryParseFriendlyUrl(SPContext.Current.Site, url, out term, out catalogUrlSegments);
                if (term != null)
                {
                    var termStoreId = term.TermSet.TermStoreId.ToString();
                    var termSetId = term.TermSet.Id.ToString();
                    var termId = term.Id.ToString();

                    pageUrl = string.Format("{0}?TermStoreId={1}&TermSetId={2}&TermId={3}", pageUrl, termStoreId, termSetId, termId);    
                }
            }

            var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.Current;
            var socialCommentManager = new SocialCommentManager(serviceContext);

            var pageUri = new Uri(pageUrl);

            commentsCount = socialCommentManager.GetCount(pageUri).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return commentsCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really save PublishingPageAbsoluteUrl, instead have a lookup to Pages Library.. So you can access all the fields of a Page..

Once you have the lookup, you get the ListItem for Page Library, and than you can easily get the Url..